# .Net Core Shared Cookies for Local or Offline Dev

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, .net-core

I am evaluating using shared cookies for a set of .Net core apps. There would be one central app which would be configured to perform SAML authentication to our enterprise Okta, and would setup the appropriate cookie. Once authenticated, users would use a directory page to link out to whichever client app they wanted. The client apps would be able to read the cookie, but wouldn't be able to perform the SAML authentication loop themselves.

Both the central and client apps would have startup methods like whats shown below.

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...
            services.AddDataProtection()
                .SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApps");

            services
                .AddAuthentication("Identity.Application")
                .AddCookie("Identity.Application", options =>
                {
                    options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
                });
            ...
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            ...
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            ...
        }
```

When we are doing development on the client apps, will we always need to run the 'central' app on the same machine to provide authentication? Or, can we do something to supply a fake cookie of some kind when we are doing local development? It will particularly help for devs if they can alter their roles through some local configuration.

By the way, if sharing cookies like this is a bad idea for some reason, I would be interested to hear why.

If it matters, the client apps will be a mix of .Net Core 2 and 3, Angular and Blazor.

Answer (score 0):

When using ASP.NET Core Identity,Data protection keys and the app name must be shared among apps.
A common key storage location is provided to the PersistKeysToFileSystem method in the following examples.This may help.

Modification in the Startup.ConfigureServices file :

```html
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem("{PATH TO COMMON KEY RING FOLDER}")
    .SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp");

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
    options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
});
```

An authentication cookie uses the HttpRequest.PathBase as its default Cookie.Path. If the app's cookie must be shared across different base paths, Path must be overridden:

```html
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem("{PATH TO COMMON KEY RING FOLDER}")
    .SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp");

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
    options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
    options.Cookie.Path = "/";
});
```

To Share authentication cookies between ASP.NET 4.x and ASP.NET Core apps refer link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#share-authentication-cookies-between-aspnet-4x-and-aspnet-core-apps

Answer (score 0):

After some additional work, I came up with an option that will allow for local / offline dev. It doesn't require access to our SSO, and it allows devs to simulate any claims they want for testing.

When running in dev, I have `launchSettings.json` configured to use windowsAuthentication and disallow anonymousAuthentication.

Then, in dev, we use an `IClaimsTransformation` implementation to setup the claims.

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...

            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, DevClaimsTransformer>();
            }

            services.AddDataProtection()
                            .SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApps");

            services
                .AddAuthentication("Identity.Application")
                .AddCookie("Identity.Application", options =>
                {
                    options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
                });
        }
```

Then the claims transformer is just reading from a json file that defines the claims, by type.

```cs
  public class DevClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, List<DevClaim>> devRoleClaims;

        public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            if (devRoleClaims == null)
            {
                devRoleClaims =
                    JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, List<DevClaim>>>(
                        File.ReadAllText("dev-claims.json"));
            }

            var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)(principal?.Identity ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(principal)));
            if (identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                foreach (var rc in devRoleClaims)
                {
                    foreach (var c in rc.Value)
                    {
                        if (c.Active)
                        {
                            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(rc.Key, c.Claim));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        }

        private class DevClaim
        {
            public string Claim { get; set; }

            public bool Active { get; set; }
        }
    }
```